# Crashpad how to set the dump level in windows? I want to adjust to Full dump。

Tags: c++, crashpad

I saw the following passage on the official website, but I don't know how to set it

Crash Dump Creation
To create a crash dump, a subset of the machine, OS and application state is grabbed from the crashed process into an in-memory snapshot structure in the handler process. Since the full application state is typically too large for capturing to disk and transmitting to an upstream server, the snapshot contains a heuristically selected subset of the full state.

The precise details of what’s captured varies between operating systems, but generally includes the following

The set of modules (executable, shared libraries) that are loaded into the crashing process.
An enumeration of the threads running in the crashing process, including the register contents and the contents of stack memory of each thread.
A selection of the OS-related state of the process, such as e.g. the command line, environment and so on.
A selection of memory potentially referenced from registers and from stack.
To capture a crash dump, the crashing process is first suspended, then a snapshot is created in the handler process. The snapshot includes the CrashpadInfo structures of the modules loaded into the process, **and the contents of those is used to control the level of detail captured for the crash dump.**

Once the snapshot has been constructed, it is then written to a minidump file, which is added to the database. The process is un-suspended after the minidump file has been written. In the case of a crash (as opposed to a client request to produce a dump without crashing), it is then either killed by the operating system or the Crashpad handler.

In general the snapshotting process has to be very intimate with the operating system it’s working with, so there will be a set of concrete implementation classes, many deriving from the snapshot interfaces, doing this for each operating system.

I tried to increase its internal MINIDUMP_TYPE enumeration with MiniDumpWithFullMemory = 0x00000002, and replaced all MiniDumpNormal with MiniDumpWithFullMemory but it didn't seem to work

Comment: What information is it missing that you are trying to get? `MiniDumpWithFullMemory` is usually more than sufficient.

Comment: Currently it is MiniDumpNormal, I don’t know how to modify it to MiniDumpWithFullMemory

Comment: Are you compiling the code yourself? Something like: `MiniDumpWriteDump( GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentProcessId(), hDumpFile, MiniDumpWithFullMemory, &ExpParam, NULL, NULL );` is what you're looking for. If what you are using is precompiled, then you'd probably be stuck with what it's already doing.

Comment: I compiled Crashpad in vcpkg, and modified part of its code, but it didn't work. It didn't call MiniDumpWriteDump internally. I want to use its mechanism of catching exceptions outside the process.